# What is the main differences between site definition and site template?

Tags: sharepoint

What is the main differences between site definition and site template?

Answer (score 3):

A **site definition** is the basic blueprint for a site, including how it looks, what lists it contains, default navigational structures, and so on. You normally create a site definition by hand-editing CAML.

A **site template** can be created from within the Sharepoint application, and is basically a  "diff" between the site definition and any changes made since the site was created. A site template is based on the underlying site definition, which means that if you create a new site from a template, and later change the underlying site definition, you run the very real risk of irreversibly screwing up your site.

A best practice is to configure a minimal site definition that, once created, is never modified again, and use site templates to store reusable customizations.

Answer (score 2):

- **Feature Stapling**

  - *Site Definition*: Supported
  - *Site Template*: Not supported
- **Multiple webs**

  - *Site Definition*: Can provision multiple webs.
  - *Site Template*: Can only provision one web.
- **Complexity**

  - *Site Definition*: Complex to create
  - *Site Template*: Easier to create
- **Permissions**

  - *Site Definition*: Requires admin access to server for deploying.
  - *Site Template*: Installable from a Web UI by site owners.
- **Performance**

  - *Site Definition*: Files are on disk, better performance.
  - *Site Template*: Files are in database, less efficient.

Comment: I tried to edit your answer for better readability, but I am not familiar with this topic. Could you please check that this is still what you wanted to say?

Comment: ok good editing but previous also same answer iam giving simple answer finally thanks for editing

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of main differences. Depends on what you are looking for:

Deciding Between Custom Web Templates and Custom Site Definitions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979683.aspx